# Use a non-standard Maven repo location for a gradle build

Tags: java, maven, gradle

For build automation, we use a non-standard Maven repository location, which is defined in a settings file like this:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>/some/place/repository</localRepository>
     ... other stuff
</settings>
```

Maven is invoked as `mvn --settings settings.xml`.

Now we have one extra project, which uses gradle. How do I best convince gradle to use the same non-standard repo for both checking packages it depends on, and publishing its artifacts that other (maven) projects may depend on?

The `build.gradle` file currently looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.3.4'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    ....
}

task uberJar(type: Jar) {
    description = 'Make JAR with all the dependencies included'
    classifier = 'uber'
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    from sourceSets.main.output
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.directory ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    description = 'Make JAR of all the source files'
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourceJar
            artifact jar
        }
    }
}
```

I attempted to add this per description at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "/some/place/repository"
        }
    }
}
```

but gradle still puts things into `~/.m2/repository`. How do I make this work?

Comment: Neither of the two answers below worked for me. No change in behavior. I decided it was simpler to create a maven pom than to figure out how to get gradle to do what I want it to do ...

Comment: You might not be using the correct gradle task. I add a similar issue. Using 'publishToMavenLocal' published to the .m2 directory while 'publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository' was publishing to my non-standard location.

Answer (score 1):

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url file('/some/place/repository')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the `repositories` declaration and the `publications` in the same `publishing` block like this:

```
publishing {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url file('/some/place/repository')
    }
  }
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
      artifact sourceJar
      artifact jar
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally add the snippet from @lance-java's answer to make the artifacts in the custom repo available to other projects:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url file('/some/place/repository')
  }
}
```